# Spring Boot app on localhost: connection refused

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app which runs fine 80% of the time.

In the other 20% however, I get "refused to connect" errors on localhost. What I have tried:

- changing ports
- turning windows defender/firewall completely off
- restarting

Nothing works. Then after a while when I keep the app running, it suddenly starts working again.

As you might know this is really bad for my workflow. I only have had this problem with Spring Boot apps.

But if I check the logs, when trying to connect nothing gets logged: these connection attempts don't even reach my app. I'm running on an embedded server under Windows 10.

It might be the server blocks incoming connections, and if so, why?

Everything here runs on localhost. Basically trying to open my spring boot app in chrome. Yet neither chrome nor anything on the local network can reach my spring boot app.

Any ideas where to proceed with this?

Comment: On what port are you running it? Also, what is the underlying web server that you're using for Spring Boot? Is it listening on all interfaces? How many network interfaces are you on? What version of Java is this?

Comment: Tried a lot of ports. Generally I'm running this on 8580. Wireshark shows me the connection tries but there is never any answer. The server is an embedded tomcat. The tomcat access logs are empty. I'm on one network via ethernet. Running Java 8.

Comment: Did you also try this in the default port - 8080 ? And he same issue happening there too ?

Comment: Have you tried turning on debug logs?

Comment: Yes, tomcat logs are in debug mode. Nothing is on the console nor in log files. Spring logs run well otherwise but they show nothing about any incoming connections in these cases. When it runs well I can see requests/responses normally in all logs.

Comment: Leaving myself  comment for a future me: running a tomcat server inside wsl2 also gave me a err_connection_refused. Restarting wsl2 fixed this (via services.msc and restart LxssManager)

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this one out, so turns out, if you're using Quartz for task scheduling, Quartz WILL block your incoming requests in some way until it handles all the triggers it was supposed to fire while the server was off. So the longer you waited between runs the longer you have to wait while Quartz fixes itself. The solution for local work is simply to turn Quartz off unless you're debugging Quartz itself.

Super weird, took me months to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Old Question, by in my case this was the solution:

1. End eclipse and all potentially running java/spring processs
2. Delete /target directory contents
3. Start eclipse
4. clean project
5. run app